# About dragging images with Squish for Windows using Image-Based Testing

Tags: python, testing, squish

I am executing automation testing with Squish for Windows using Image-Based Testing. But some of the events are not working!

For example, i have a control looking like this:
[My sample control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lej11.jpg)

I would like to hold and drag it to a specific position (when cropping images) but i can't figure how to do it with Squish yet.
I want something like this:
*mouseDrag(waitForObject(":_CropTopButton"), 5, 30, 0, 280)*

But with Image-Based Testing, it won't work. Only mouseClick(), doubleClick() and tapObject() are supported! (As far as i know)

**Is there any way to treat (or drag) images like a control-object with Squish for Windows using Image-Based Testing?**
I'm completely new to Squish, StackOverFlow and writing in English so if anything is inappropriate or annoyed, please be kind enough to let me know, thank you so so much!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the functions [mouseMove()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#mouseMove-function), [mousePress() [Windows]](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-windowsconvenienceapi.html#win-mousePress-function), [mouseRelease() [Windows]](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-windowsconvenienceapi.html#win-mouseRelease-function). Whether that triggers a drag may depend. You may have to "wiggle" the mouse back and forth a few pixels in a long/short enough amount of time to trigger it.

As for supporting mouseDrag() for the image objects, please contact the vendor regarding that.